# How can I make this only match the words after the word 'speaks' and ignore commas and spaces

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEX:

```
/(?<=\w\sspeaks\s)(?!,|\s|\.)([\w]+)/gmi
```

The string is:

```
Example Person speaks ExampleLanguage1, ExampleLanguage2, ExampleLanguage3 and ExampleLanguage4.
Example Person two speaks ExampleLanguage1, ExampleLanguage2, ExampleLanguage3 and ExampleLanguage4.
Example Person three speaks ExampleLanguage1 and ExampleLanguage2.
```

For me, the above only matches:

```
ExampleLanguage1
ExampleLanguage1
ExampleLanguage1
```

I want to match:

```
ExampleLanguage1
ExampleLanguage2
ExampleLanguage3
ExampleLanguage4
ExampleLanguage1
ExampleLanguage2
ExampleLanguage3
ExampleLanguage4
ExampleLanguage1
ExampleLanguage2
```

The words *Example Person* can be any word, even without space in-between.
And the words *ExampleLanguage* do not have numbers marked. And they also can have spaces, and can be any word.

Here is a link to it: https://regex101.com/r/MjL8cW/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(?<=\bspeaks\b.*?)\b\w{4,}\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/c3eHgz/2).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    speaks                   'speaks'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w{4,}                   word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (at
                           least 4 times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

**Demo**

```js
const string = `Example Person speaks ExampleLanguage1, ExampleLanguage2, ExampleLanguage3 and ExampleLanguage4.
Example Person two speaks ExampleLanguage1, ExampleLanguage2, ExampleLanguage3 and ExampleLanguage4.
Example Person three speaks ExampleLanguage1 and ExampleLanguage2.`
console.log(string.match(/(?<=\bspeaks\b.*?)\b\w{4,}\b/gi))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can make use of the `\G` anchor, you might match 4 or more word characters, or match words with 1-3 characters and use `\K` to clear the match buffer.

```
(?:^.*?\hspeaks|\w{1,3}|\G(?!^))[,.]?\h+\K\w{4,}
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^.*?\hspeaks` Match From the start of the string till the first occurrence of a whitespace char and speaks.
  - `|` Or
  - `\w{1,3}` Match 1-3 word chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, but not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `[,.]?\h+` Match an optional `,` or `.` and 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `\K\w{4,}` Forget what is matched until so far using `\K` and match 4 or more word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EetTRw/1)

Comment: But, I only want to match those. I do not want to use groups! I know it is complicated, but I'm sure it is possible.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana Like this? `(?:^.*?\sspeaks|\w{1,3}|\G(?!^))[,.]?\h*\K\w{4,}` https://regex101.com/r/f6oYA4/1

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: "Ignore commas and spaces" can you make a temporary `String`, replace commas and spaces with empty string (`String temp = origStr.replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")`) and the evaluate your regex against `temp`? I would think doing this should make your regex simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The continue operator seems to be the right thing here. The accepted is fine but there is a problem with 3 letter languages, like Yao, Min, Mon (spoken in [Afrika](https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/african_languages.htm), [Asia](https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/asian_languages.htm)...)

Try something along this lines:

```
(?i)(?:speaks\s*\K|(?<!^)\G(?:,|,?\s*and)\s*\K)(?-i)([A-Z](?i)\w+)
```

[Demo](https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/asian_languages.htm)

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana well, it can be still a problem to rely on the length of the language. Just saying; the other solution is good as well, nevertheless.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana https://regex101.com/r/EetTRw/2

Comment: didn't concentrate on that.. oops